# How can i add dynamic row to dynamic column?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new on flutter. How can i add dynamic row to dynamic column? I tried this code in stateful widget but didn't change result. Thanks.

I am getting this error.

```
The following UnsupportedError was thrown building MyApp(dirty):
Unsupported operation: add
```

main.dart

```
 import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

 void main() {
 runApp(const MyApp());
 }

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
 const MyApp({super.key});

 final Row rw = const Row(
   children: [Text("cell1"), Text("cell2"), Text("cell3")],
 );

 final Column col = const Column();

 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
     col.children.add(rw);
   }
   return MaterialApp(
       home: col,
      );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, you can't add the children in a column like that. In Flutter, widgets are immutable, meaning their properties cannot be changed once they're created.

To achieve what you want, you can try this. In short, you need only to change the list of the widget or children of the columns.

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    void main() {
      runApp(const MyApp());
    }
    
    class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
      const MyApp({super.key});
    
      final row = const Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        children: const [
          Text("Cell 1"),
          Text("Cell 2"),
          Text("Cell 3"),
        ],
      );
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return MaterialApp(
          home: Scaffold(
            body: Column(
              children: [
                for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++) row,
              ],
            ),
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, I understood how to do it now.